# Adding geometry (Ctrl+1) does not work as expected

Tags: modeling, geometry

Sorry for the weird title, I didn't know how to express it better.

I have created a cube to form a hat.
I then extruded the 4 bottom vertices. 
I did not move them after extruding, but I simply scaled them.

Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to add geometry. 
For some reason, the hat brim is much smaller than I expected.

Shouldn't the hat brim be as large as the 4 extruded, scaled bottom vertices?

And does anybody perhaps see why the hat brim gets doubled vertices?

Thank you for the help!
[image]

Comment: @cegaton Shouldn't this be an answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> you added a **Subsurf Modifier** with one subdivision. The default subdivision agorithm is Catmull-Clark, which tends to round off the geometry, hence the roundness you see in the ghosted image. On the modifier you can change the subdivision from Catmull-Clark to Simple.

[image]

Comment: But what about the double vertices? You don't get them, I think.

Comment: @JohannHesters those double vertices are caused by the bottom face. You can delete that since you are trying to do a hat...